# Update multiple records with concatenating string+'number increment'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called 'bbe.case' with the following example data:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|            Id       |     Name         |      Phone       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3455       |      Johny       |       `123456    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3457       |      Dora        |       342754     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Instead having the real name in the Name column, I would like to change to 'Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3' ... 'Name 1003' and so on, like the following:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|           Id        |     Name         |      Phone       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3455       |      Name 1      |       123456     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3457       |      Name 2      |       342754     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|

'
'
'
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          4453       |      Name 999    |       12345      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          4454       |      Name 1000   |       345754     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Appreciate any guidance on this.

Comment: please show your attempted query

Comment: You may take a look at the documentation on `update`, `row_number()` , `concat()`

Comment: Does it need to be consistent, i.e. if id 4453 is name 999 today, does it still need to be name 999 tomorrow when the data has changed? It would potentially be much easier to derive a new number from the ID than to make one up.

Comment: @DaleK it does not need to be consistent between id and name.  The data is fixed, wont change anymore.

Comment: As Squirrel said, try [`row_number`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and see how you get on.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this sample match your requiremnts:

```
CREATE TABLE  #TempTbl (
[Id] int,
[Name] nvarchar(255),
[Phone] nvarchar(255)    
)

INSERT INTO #TempTbl
VALUES 
    (20, 'Johny', '514545'),
    (30, 'Hassan', '514545'),
    (40, 'Yahya', '514545'),
    (50, 'Waleed', '514545'),
    (60, 'Shreem', '514545')


UPDATE t
SET t.[Name] = d.[NewName]
FROM #TempTbl t JOIN (
        SELECT t.[Id], CONCAT('Name ', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Id])) AS 'NewName', t.Phone
        FROM #TempTbl t
                     ) d ON t.[Id] = d.[Id]


SELECT * FROM #TempTbl
```